# Converting Linux codes to Batch file format

Tags: linux, batch-file

What is this block of code from linux intended to do and how do i code the same thing in batch file format to do the same?

```
create_db() {

  echo -e "\nRe-creating database [$DB] . . .\n"
  apps_id=`db2 list applications | grep $DB | cut -c25-30`
  for i in $apps_id
  do
    db2 "force applications ($i)"
  done
  sleep 3

  db2 drop db $DB
  db2 create database $DB

  cd $HOME_DIR
  cd ../Db/bin
  [ ! -d logs ] && (mkdir logs)
  rm -f logs/*

  db2 connect to $DB user $USER using $PASS
```

Comment: care to explain what a batch file is? You mean a windows cmd.exe batch file? If so, what version of windows? Look at powershell as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code tries to recreate a DB2 database specified in the `$DB` variable  by (1) first listing all the active connections to the database; (2) closing down all those connections; (3) erasing the database (4) recreating the database (5) erasing all the logs (6) connecting the user `$user` to the database.

A first approach in windows would be something similar to this

```
:create_db
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
ECHO Re-creating database %DB%
FOR /F "tokens=3" %%A IN ('DB2 LIST APPLICATIONS FOR DATABASE %DB%') DO (
  SET APPHANDLE=%%A
  if .!ID!==. (SET ID=!APPHANDLE!) ELSE (SET ID=!ID!,!APPHANDLE!)
)  
DB2 FORCE APPLICATIONS(!ID!)
SLEEP 3
DB2 DROP DB %DB%
DB2 CREATE DATABASE %DB%
cd %HOMEPATH%
cd ..\DB\BIN
rd /S /Q LOGS
md LOGS
db2 connect to %DB% user %USER% using %PASS%
endlocal
goto :eof
```

Some caveats, though.

GREP and CUT are not standard commands in windows. I have re implemented the code with a slightly different strategy. Test carefully.

SLEEP is not an standard command in Windows. Some implementations and some alternatives exist, research yourself (here in SO for example) and you'll find them.

Comment: That was marvelous, am very new to linux and coding in ms dos batch. i am having an internship and my supervisor asked me to do a conversion of about 150 lines...i have never coded in linux nor batch file format before but i tot i could just follow the sequence and understand what needs to be done and just modify the codes with some help from google. your explanation really made sense. a lot of sense but i couldnt really grab the concept because its as though the linux codes used methods and the batch used functions. id be glad if you can help me out on this one.i cant thank yo enough....

Answer (score 0):

I'd use cygwin bash (www.cygwin.com) and keep the script.

There is msys for windows as well, and perhaps another minimal bash implementation, but I personally prefer cygwin on windows